# How to tag a user using the discord.Member argument?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot with the command `!sad`. On execution the bot should reply with a random `string` from `sad_list`.

```
sad_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"]

@client.command()
async def sad(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    print("running 'sad'")
    
    if user is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")
```

I want the option to have the bot tag someone if you execute the command with the `user: discord.Member` argument.

Preferred output:

```
@user#0000 [positive message] <3
```

as opposed to only

```
[Positive message] <3
```

The following has already been tried:

```
if user is None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author} {sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user} {sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")
```

However this simply writes:

```
user#0000 [positive comment] <3
```

As opposed to actually mentioning them

Comment: Why not - `ctx.send(f"@{user} {sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")`

Comment: @PCM That makes the bot say `@user#0000 [positive message] <3`. But not actually mention the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `user.mention` to mention users

`await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} {sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=user%20mention#discord.User.mention

For future references, you could also mention users like this: `<@!user_id>`, replace `user_id` with the actual ID of the user. You can use this in cases where `user.mention` is not practical.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to mention the user you just type

`await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} {sad_list[randint(0, len(sad_list))]} <3")`